# Loop until there is parent_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Need help to shorten this code.logic is until there is a parent_id in each location push the ids to `_location_ids`

Here is my code

```rb
     location_ids = location_id.map{|a| a.location_id}.uniq.sort #if location_id
     second_level_parent_ids = []

     location_ids.each do |loc|
         _location = Location.select(:parent_id).find(loc)
         if !_location.parent_id.nil?
             second_level_parent_ids.push(_location.parent_id)
         end
     end

     second_level_parent_ids = second_level_parent_ids.uniq.sort

     third_level_parent_ids = []
     second_level_parent_ids.each do |second_id|
         _location = Location.select(:parent_id).find(second_id)
         if !_location.parent_id.nil?
             third_level_parent_ids.push(_location.parent_id)
         end
     end

    _location_ids = location_ids + second_level_parent_ids + third_level_parent_ids
```

sample table fields: [fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOtMc.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do the heavy lifting in the database instead of loading the records into memory.

Add this to your `Location` model at `app/models/location.rb`

```
scope :with_parent_by_id, ->(ids) { where(id: ids).where.not(parent_id: nil) }
scope :distinct_by_parent, -> { order(:parent_id).distinct }

def self.uniq_present_parent_ids_for(ids)
  with_parent_by_id(idsids).distinct_by_parent.pluck(:parent_id)
end
```

and use it like this at the place of the example from your question

```
location_ids = location_id.map(&:location_id).sort
second_level_parent_ids = Location.uniq_present_parent_ids_for(location_ids)
third_level_parent_ids = Location.uniq_present_parent_ids_for(second_level_parent_ids)

_location_ids = (location_ids + second_level_parent_ids + third_level_parent_ids)
```

Comment: thank you for this. your code looks simpler and faster.